# C 2d strings issue

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>



#include<string.h>
     void fill_A (char A[][10],int *pos1,int *pos2)

   {
     int j,k,l;
     while (j=0)
     {
          k=0;
          do{
               printf("keep entering and terminate by end");
               gets(A[k]); k++;}while(strcmp(A[k-1],"end")!=0);
               *pos2=k-1;
          for(l=0;l<k;l++)
          {
               if (strcmp(A[l],"middle")==0)
               {
                    j=1; *pos1=l; break; }
          }
     }
}     

void fill_B(char A[][10],char B[][10],int pos1)
{
     int j,k;
     for(j=0;j<pos1;j++)
     {
          strcpy(B[j],A[j]);
     }
}

void fill_C(char A[][10],char C[][10],int pos1,int pos2)
{
     int j;
     for (j=pos1;j<pos2;j++)
     {
          strcpy(C[j],A[j]);
     }
}

void print (char A[][10],int lim)
{
     int j;
     for (j=0;j<lim;j++)
     {
          puts(A[j]);
     }
}

void main()
{
     char A[100][10],B[100][10],C[100][10];
     int pos1,pos2;
     fill_A(A,&pos1,&pos2);
     fill_B(A,B,pos1);
     fill_C(A,C,pos1,pos2);
     print (B,pos1);
     print(C,pos2-pos1);
}
```

I am trying to:
1)Keep entering strings until terminated by user (entering end)
2) the list of strings should have a string "middle"
3) words before middle put in 2d string B
4) words between middle and end put in 2d string C.

Run: just a screen that I cannot type into.

Can you find the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: **gets(A[k]);**    is not a suitable input function, it is not used correctly here.

Comment: `while (j=0)` should be `j=0; while (j==0)`.